# Merging content of 2 files based on some common field

Tags: awk

**file 1**

```
a,b, c, d,session-111, e, f
p,f, y, j,session-222, e, o
p,e, c, j,session-333, e, r
t,y, u, j,session-444, r, r
t,y, u, j,session-555, e, w
e,g, m, j,session-555, e, m
e,e, m, j,session-555, e, m
```

**file 2**

```
session-111, data-123, 123, erwt
session-222, data-234, 345, fghjf
session-333, data-345, 456, aasdf
session-555, data-567, 789, aasdf
session-555, data-890, 121, aasdf
session-666, data-678, 121, aasdf
```

**Output**

```
a,b, c, d,session-111, e, f, data-123, 123
p,f, y, j,session-222, e, o, data-234, 345
p,e, c, j,session-333, e, r, data-345, 456
t,y, u, j,session-444, e, r, NODATA
t,y, u, j,session-555, e, r, date-567, 789
t,y, u, j,session-555, e, r, date-890, 121
e,e, m, j,session-555, e, m, NODATA
```

All data from file1 should be printed - no matter there is reference found in file2 or not
if reference found in file 2, then specific fields (field 2 and 3) will get concatinated in output file

Comment: Please look at my answer for how to do a join and either fix your expected output or update your question to clearly describe what you actually want.

Comment: Voting to close as question is unlikely to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to sequentially match fields 5 and 1 in file1 to file2 respectively, and if there is no match a "NODATA" field should be used instead. The following comes close to what you want, I think your listed output has some errors, see the comments made by sudo_O:

*parse.awk*

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
FNR == NR { 
  lines[$1][++count[$1]] = $2 FS $3
  next
} 

count[$5] == 0 { print $0, " NODATA" } 
count[$5]  > 0 {
  count[$5]--
  print $0, lines[$5][++prn[$5]]
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk file2 file1
```

Output:

```
a,b, c, d,session-111, e, f, data-123, 123
p,f, y, j,session-222, e, o, data-234, 345
p,e, c, j,session-333, e, r, data-345, 456
t,y, u, j,session-444, r, r, NODATA
t,y, u, j,session-555, e, w, data-567, 789
e,g, m, j,session-555, e, m, data-890, 121
e,e, m, j,session-555, e, m, NODATA
```

Comment: Hello Thor, right now I am getting syntax error with your command.. could you please help

Comment: I think it may be awk version.. now it's working after modification like : rewriting array lines[$1][++count[$1]] as lines[$1, ++count[$1]].. Thank you so much Thor :)

Answer (score 1):

try this one-liner:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{k[$1]=$2 OFS $3;next} {if($5 in k)print $0,k[$5];else print $0," NODATA"}'  OFS="," file2 file1
a,b, c, d,session-111, e, f, data-123, 123
p,f, y, j,session-222, e, o, data-234, 345
p,e, c, j,session-333, e, r, data-345, 456
t,y, u, j,session-444, r, r, NODATA
t,y, u, j,session-555, e, w, data-890, 121
e,g, m, j,session-555, e, m, data-890, 121
e,e, m, j,session-555, e, m, data-890, 121
```

Comment: There are three of these on file 1, session-555, two of which are to "match" file 2, with different data, and the third is to come up with "NODATA" as the other matches have "used up" all the session-555s available.